# How to trigger conditional based on object presence on object's attribute route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, conditional-statements, undefined

Challenges fall within one of 5 categorizations:

```
  CATEGORIZATION = ['adventure', 'health', 'work', 'gift', 'wacky']
  scope :adventure,  -> { where(categorization: 'adventure') }
  scope :health,  -> { where(categorization: 'health') }
  scope :work,  -> { where(categorization: 'work') }
  scope :gift,  -> { where(categorization: 'gift') }
  scope :wacky,  -> { where(categorization: 'wacky') }
```

If a user clicks, for example...

```
<% if challenge.categorization == "work" %>
  <%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :work) do %>    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>
  <% end %>
<% elsif challenge.categorization == "gift" %> etc...
```

He is taken to...

Route: `http://www.livetochallenge.com/categorization?categorization=work`

This page will list all his challenges that have the categorization: `work`.

```
@challenges = current_user.challenges.send(params[:categorization]).order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge }
@challenges_by_date = (@challenges).group_by { |t| [t.deadline.year, t.deadline.month] }
```

But if the user doesn't have any challenges with the categorization: `work` then how can I use a conditional to trigger the text on the page, "You have no challenges for this category"?

I tried this...

```
<% if @challenges.categorization.nil? %>
  You have no challenges for this category.
<% end %>
```

But I get the error `undefined method .categorization' for #<Array:0x007fe6bfdeaed8>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<% if @challenges.none?{ |challenge| challenge.categorization } %>
  You have no challenges for this category.
<% end %>
```

Better solution:

```
# assuming that the foreign key is categorization_id
@challenges.any?(&:categorization_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Chech this out:

```
if @challenges.none? { |c| c.categorization }
```

Sidenote:

You could shorten your `scope`s definition:

```
  CATEGORIZATION = %w(adventure health work gift wacky).freeze
  CATEGORIZATION.each do |categorization|
    scope categorization.to_sym, -> { where(categorization: categorization) }
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the error `undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x007fe6c3073878>`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I've updated the answer, so it should be fine now

Comment: Thanks for the sidenote. I'll def implement that :) Tan's answer got at the larger problem for me